# Implementing a web page hit counter in 2013

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to implement a web page hit counter to let the server know what pages are being viewed where I'm trying to avoid sending the server repetitive 'user hits' by the same user, same page. (I'm not super concerned about them clearing their cache etc. and possibly getting counted again)

I've generally seen something like this:

```
<img src="/the-hit-counter?pageId=SOME_PAGE_ID" />
```

and then use a cookie to make sure the 'hit' doesn't get counted again.

But is there any reason to not use AJAX to notify the server other than the obvious "the user must have JavaScript enabled"? I'm guessing almost everyone that isn't wearing a tin-foil hat these days will have it enabled in their browser.

With AJAX and JavaScript I could do something like this and bring local storage into the mix and reduce some network bandwidth:

```
if (!amplify.store('SOME_PAGE_ID')) {
    $.get('/the-hit-counter?pageId=SOME_PAGE_ID');
    amplify.store('SOME_PAGE_ID', "");
}
```

What am I missing about the JavaScript approach?

Comment: can't really expect everyone to be using javascript.  security isn't the only reason why it wouldn't be enabled.

Comment: I suppose. Google Analytics (one of the answers below) requires it though even as far as I can tell!

Comment: @JohnCulviner But GA does not seem to provide a way to display hit count on your web page. Any ideas?

Comment: DIY from scratch is what I did!

Answer (score 9):

I think the 2013 way to do this is to just sign up for [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), and paste its generated JavaScript into your site. Much easier than rolling your own solution, and you get a wealth of user data (demographics, locations, accurate user counts, etc.).

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this question is being upvoted. Indeed Google Analytics is the proper way of going about this, as a hit counter by itself is absolutely meaningless and completely stupid...due to no analytical data provided just by simple numbers......

Comment: I hear you, I love GA! We have our own internal tracking that needs to be populated and this is a CMS that hosts multiple 'domains' so GA isn't really an option. Good idea though!

Comment: Geoffrey> What if we want to display the hit count on our webpage - GA doesn't seem to provide a way to do that! Any ideas?

Comment: GA has an API, presumably you could call it to get the number of hits and then output that. You would need to make this call server-side, so as not to reveal your GA credentials, and once you've gone through _that_ much trouble it's probably easier to just build your own count tracker.

Comment: Google Analytics provides views per URL; assuming each of your posts has a unique (and canonical) URL, which is probably the case, then you can get a count of views per URL/post.